# Powershell: I have split a string, now I want to extract the 3 digit number instead of a 2 or 4 digit number

Tags: arrays, parsing, powershell, numbers

So I am making a file parser to take data and output it to a new file in a new format.

Currently, I have found the file, found strings with the keyword "excluded" while eliminating specific cases. I split the strings by the semi colons, and I tried getting the 3 digit device code by making an array based on position, but some files have an extra colon in the description that will offset the count by one or two places.

Here is my code:

```
#This is a program to scan for excluded devices and export their information into a .dff file

$deviceArray = {$deviceArray}.Invoke()
$eliminations = @("( Matched Device )", "will not attempt", "HBA")


while(1<#Psuite test is running#>) #Check for psuite process in get-process or get-service
{
    $search = Select-string -path N:\my\path\name\report.txt -pattern EXCLUDED -quiet
    $search

    if($search)
    {
        $excluded = Select-String -path N:\my\path\name\report.txt -pattern EXCLUDED | Select-String -pattern $eliminations -notmatch
        $excluded
        $count = ($excluded -split ":").count

        for($i = 3; $i -lt $count; $i += 10)
        {
            $deviceArray.Add(($excluded -split ":")[$i])
        }
        $deviceArray

        #select-string -- SPT:Id,NOT TESTED | select-string 
        #Select-string Logical Volume List -Context 0,


    }
    sleep -s 2700  
}
```

**The output from my file is:**

N:\my\path\name\report.txt:1727:105:03:1i:01:06 SRB:Phy00 EXCLUDED FROM TEST - LOG PAGE DATA

N:\my\path\name\report.txt:1944:057:01:1e:01:02 SRB:Phy00 EXCLUDED FROM TEST - LOG PAGE DATA

105

105

01

**The expected output should be:**

N:\my\path\name\report.txt:1727:105:03:1i:01:06 SRB:Phy00 EXCLUDED FROM TEST - LOG PAGE DATA

N:\my\path\name\report.txt:1944:057:01:1e:01:02 SRB:Phy00 EXCLUDED FROM TEST - LOG PAGE DATA

105

057

It worked with my first file, it worked perfectly, but with this one there is an extra colon in the SRB:phy00 that is messing up the count.

My new idea is to search for 3 digit numbers instead of finding by line number. I am not sure now to do that. I tried using the -like, but it didn't work out. Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT: I have been using regex now instead of splitting it, but I still have run into a problem where it doesn't work.**

I have added

```
$matches = [regex]::matches($excluded, ":\d{3}:")
```

instead of $count assignment and I have changed

```
$deviceArray.Add(($excluded -split ":")[$i])
```

to

```
$deviceArray.Add($matches[$i] -replace (":", "")[$i])
```

and modified the for statement to start at zero and increment through the $matches variable by using

```
or($i = 0; $i -ne $null; $i ++)
```

I am still left with no value on the $deviceArray. It just comes out as an array full of nothing. (not an array with no values)

**EDIT: SOLVED
With the replacements added using [regex]::, it negated the need for the loop. I removed the for loop and the matches array indexing and it worked.**

Comment: Can we see sample input and expected output for this? So we know exactly what you are starting with and what you expect to see as a result. Or is that what the last part of your question is?

Comment: Hate to say this, but you should probably break your operations into intermediate products and pipe those to `Out-Host` to see what's going on.